# Mocking Web API call in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

i have mvc application which call the WEB API using the restsharp . i am writing the test cases for the MVC application. test case execution fails in the debug mode when it hit to the Web API below is the MVC code

```
public JsonResult GetCustomerInforGrid(string ddlItem, string Searchtext)
{
    CustomerInfoModel customerinfor = new CustomerInfoModel();
    List<CustomerInfoModel> listcustomerinfor = new List<CustomerInfoModel>();
    var restClient = new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SWBWebApiBaseUri"]);
    var request = new RestRequest("api/CustomerInfo/GetCustomerInfo/{ddlItem}/{Searchtext}", Method.GET);
    request.AddParameter("ddlItem", ddlItem, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    request.AddParameter("Searchtext", Searchtext, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    var varexceptionlist = restClient.Execute<List<CustomerInfoModel>>(request);

    foreach (var item in varexceptionlist.Data)
    {
        listcustomerinfor.Add(item);
    }

    return Json(listcustomerinfor, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

below is the code written in the MS test i am trying to mock it but not sure how to do. kindly provide the help/suggestion how to test the MVC controller

```
[TestMethod]
public void SearchCustomer()
{
    String GCIN = "GC007637306A";
    CustomerInfoModel CIM = new CustomerInfoModel();

    CustomerInfoController controller = new CustomerInfoController();
    //HomeController controller = new HomeController();
    //Mock Request.Url.AbsoluteUri 
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://mySomething", "");
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
    HttpContext httpContextMock = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(
                                   new HttpContextWrapper(httpContextMock), 
                                   new RouteData(), controller);

    CIM.CustomerName = "XXX XXXXX 549224361A";

    CustomerInfoController CI = new CustomerInfoController();
    controller.GetCustomerInforGrid("GCIN", GCIN);

    Assert.Equals(CIM, CI);
}
```

Comment: Maybe a HttpMessageHandler that intercepts request and returns what you expect from the web api

Comment: in the debug mode controller hits the line rest client but it fails to get the configuration setting ... can you help me with the code how to over come this issue

Comment: I don't understand your test method code; Your assert compare 2 diffrent types: `CustomerInfoModel` and `CustomerInfoController`...(`Assert.Equals(CIM, CI);`). BTW where do initialize the server?

Comment: test method i put us to show how i am trying it Assert.Equals(CIM, controller);.... but problem is how i will get start the web api when i am running the test cases for the mvc .... is there any intialization i need to do so that MS test can read the web config path of the API get the value from the DB @OldFox

Comment: You should search for `SelfHostServer`, for example; [an aesy way to write integration test with web api](http://tostring.it/2012/07/23/an-easy-way-to-write-an-integration-test-with-web-api/)